# Need advice fixing this source error in Kali Linux

Tags: command-line, kali-linux, source

```
W: GPG error: http://http.kali `enter code here`.org kali Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>

*This is the result i receive after trying to update the signature* "Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.aOUagKwz1w --trustdb-name /etc/apt//trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//kali-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver http://http.kali .org --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
gpg: requesting key 7D8D0BF6 from http server http.kali .org
gpgkeys: no key data found for http://http.kali. org/
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0 "
```

Comment: Your sources are not properly signed. You find a different download.

Comment: i searched the official kali linux sources and changed my sources.list file to just the official sources, when that failed i tried the official and source repos, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Some keys are missing to validate your packets. Without them, a man-in-the-middle attacker could modify your downloaded packages to inject trojan to your computer.

Keys can be downloaded from keyservers. They use tricky protocols, these can't be hacked on this way.

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the signature first:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver http://http.kali.org --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6`,

AND then rebuild your software cache:

`cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: After all steps i get the same result, but im editing my question to show the result of me trying to update the signature

Comment: I messed the format all up, wouldnt let me post links the regular way sorry